# Using a list of Integers to retrieve a list of Tuples in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Here is the layout of my problem:

```
ids :: [Integer]  -- A list of Integers.                                                

db :: [(Integer, Name)]  -- A list of integer ids with the corresponding names
```

How do I retrieve every tuple from the `db` where the id from the tuple matches at least one integer from my `ids` list?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: the `filter`, `fst` and `elem` functions will probably be useful here.

Comment: Also, [`Data.List.lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:lookup), as it's very close to what you want already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `filter` function:

```
query = filter (\t -> fst t `elem` ids) db
```

or more "elegant" pointfree version

```
query = filter ((`elem` ids) . fst) db
```

If you like list comprehensions use

```
[t | t <- db, fst t `elem` ids]
```

Comment: You could also pattern match `t`, i.e. `\(a,_) -> elem a ids` (don’t know how to escape backticks)

Comment: You use double backticks  ;)